# Setting expandable list view scrolling

Tags: android, xml, view, scroll, expandablelistview

How i can set my exapandable list view scrolling in scroll view?

This is my code:

```
<ExpandableListView
android:id="@+id/lvExp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="250dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
android:background="@color/white"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:clickable="true"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dip"
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:transcriptMode="disabled"
android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:scrollbars="none" >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Comment: I think there is no use to use scrollview to scroll expandable list view because when ever it fills screen, it's automatically scroll up or down.